# Div element woes

Tags: html, css

It's been a while since I dabbled in web development and have recently picked it back up again. I apologize if I should be able to solve this on my own. Anywho, I'm building a website for a client. I typed in the code for the header and made it responsive. Everything looked great. Now as I'm giving everything a once over before I start testing the site, the logo is gone. Completely vanished. Mind you, I didn't touch the coding for it since I first typed it in. I tried to change the positioning of the div element to make it visible again and NOTHING! I tried changing the z-index. NOTHING! I cleaned out cache. NOTHING! I'm at the end of my rope. There are no errors in my coding. Especially since it worked before. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

```css
.logo {
  background-image: url("../Images/logo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 30%;
}

.home-header {
  display: contents;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="home-header">
  <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><span></span></a></div>
  <nav role="navigation" style="position: fixed;">
    <div id="menuToggle">
      <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger" />
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="PORTFOLIO.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="ABOUT ME.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
        <li><a href="PACKAGES.html">PACKAGES</a></li>
        <li><a href="CONTACT ME.html">CONTACT AND BOOKING</a></li>
        <div class="header-soc-media-links">
          <div class="fb-2">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/L.PProductions.Photo101/"><img width="26px" height="26px" src="Images/Facebook-link-Icon-coal.png"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="ig-2">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lamarplaterimages/"><img width="25px" height="25px" src="Images/Instagram-link-Icon-coal.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Did you check that ../Images/logo.png is still the right path to the logo?

Comment: why did you set the background width on 120%?

Comment: Instead of trying to troubleshoot each CSS property for the logo one by one, open up your browser dev tools and (1) inspect the element, is it rendered with the dimensions as expected, (2) inspect the network tab to see if the image is indeed correctly loaded.

Comment: Open up the console see if there's `Failed to load resource` type error, Also i don't understand the use of `display:contents` your logo's width/height depend on the parent's width/height which is thanks to `display:contents` is the body which is `0` even if the images loads in you won't be able to see it.

Comment: I figured it out right before I came on here to check for suggestions. Lol. Figures. Thanks so much for the suggestions. I checked the Layout tab in Inspector and noticed the actual width of the image in pixels. I typed in the same width into the CSS and the logo appeared again. It's weird how that wasn't an issue before, but I guess that's how it goes sometimes.